# Change fade out a div based on scroll with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/Fq5K4/

I want to make it so that as the user scrolls down the page, the image in the top section turns black the more i scroll down so that that whole block is completely black. This technique can be seen here:

http://www.metalabdesign.com/work/

The closest bit of code I could find is like this: http://jsfiddle.net/HsRpT/6/:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var el = $('.block');    
    var offset = el.offset();  
    var opacity = ( (offset.top - el.height() ) / 100 ) * -1;
    $('.block').css('opacity', opacity );
});
```

Comment: Use the "closest bit of code" but add an element over the whole first area that starts out transparent. Instead of going from 1 opacity to 0, go from 0 to 1 with a black background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd do that like this :

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('.block').css('opacity', function() {
        return 1 - ($(window).scrollTop() / $(this).outerHeight());
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HsRpT/134/)

[**ANOTHER FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fq5K4/1/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it not possible to utilise the existing markup rather than add an empty div? I was thinking we could apply this to mask instead?